# Cell Referencing

Tags: excel

i dont know if what im trying to do is possible,

i want to manipulate data from another sheet for example:

for example on sheet2 i would use the following formula
    =Sheet1!A1+Sheet1!A2

what i want to do is have a cell that contains the text Sheet1! and then have a formula that uses the text in that cell such like

```
sheet2 a1 = Sheet1
```

formauls in Sheet2 are like the following

```
=A1!A1+A1!A2
```

is this possible

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `INDIRECT` formula, which will take a string an convert it into a usable range. In your case, you can try putting `Sheet1` in cell `A1` on `Sheet2`, and in in cell `A2` on `Sheet2`, put the formula:

```
=INDIRECT(A1& "!A1")
```

This will take the value in `A1` (which is `Sheet1`), concatenate it with `!A1` and return the value at the string created - `Sheet1!A1`.

You can also work backwards from a cell reference to a string by using the `ADDRESS` formula, which takes (at a minimum) a row number and a column number and returns the text representation of the cell reference. For example:

```
=ADDRESS(1, 1)
```

will return the value `$A$1` in string form, which you could then pass into `INDIRECT` to get the value (this is a technique that can be be used to reference cells in a flexible/dynamic way).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `INDIRECT()` function in your formula to build the reference.

```
Sheet1!A1 = "Sheet2!"
Sheet2!A1 = "Hello World"
Sheet1!A2 = INDIRECT(A1&"A1")
Sheet1!A2 == "Hello World"
```